# Activity Correlation Query Using MySQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL noob question:

I have two entities "foo" and "bar" the activities of which I want to correlate. Specifically, I would like to determine which of the "bar" objects are active at the same times as a given "foo" object.

To that end, I have set up a simple MySQL database with two tables:

```
select * from foo;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | arrive              | depart              |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2014-10-01 08:00:00 | 2014-10-01 09:00:00 |
|    1 | 2014-10-01 10:00:00 | 2014-10-01 11:00:00 |
|    1 | 2014-10-01 12:00:00 | 2014-10-01 13:00:00 |
|    2 | 2014-10-01 09:00:00 | 2014-10-01 10:00:00 |
|    2 | 2014-10-01 12:00:00 | 2014-10-01 13:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+

select * from bar;

+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | start               | end                 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2014-10-01 08:05:00 | 2014-10-01 08:55:00 |
|    1 | 2014-10-01 09:05:00 | 2014-10-01 09:55:00 |
|    1 | 2014-10-01 11:05:00 | 2014-10-01 11:55:00 |
|    2 | 2014-10-01 11:05:00 | 2014-10-01 11:55:00 |
|    2 | 2014-10-01 12:05:00 | 2014-10-01 12:55:00 |
|    2 | 2014-10-01 07:05:00 | 2014-10-01 07:55:00 |
|    3 | 2014-10-01 08:05:00 | 2014-10-01 08:55:00 |
|    3 | 2014-10-01 10:05:00 | 2014-10-01 10:55:00 |
|    3 | 2014-10-01 12:05:00 | 2014-10-01 12:55:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Needless to say, the "arrive" and "start" columns represent the start of an activity period, the "depart" and "end" columns represent the end of each period, and the id columns are unique identifiers for each object.

As a first step, for each activity period in foo, I want to determine the set of bar objects which were active during the same time frame.

From the sample data above for foo #1: 
Between 8:00 and 9:00 (i.e. during first activity period for foo #1) bar #1 and bar #3 are both active,
between 10:00 and 11:00 only bar #3 is active,
between 12:00 and 13:00 bar #2 and bar #3 are both active, etc.

Once these sets are determined, if I can determine their intersection I will have the answer I want (e.g. bar #3 is the only bar object that is active at all of the same times as foo object #1).

I'm trying to develop a query which will return this result. Ideally this query would grind through the entire database and spit out rows that contain one "foo" id and one "bar" id where the activities coincide.

As a starting point, I came up with a query to identify all of the bar objects which are active during each period of foo activity:

```
SELECT foo.id, 
       bar.id 
FROM foo 
LEFT JOIN bar 
ON bar.start >= foo.arrive 
AND bar.end <= foo.depart;
```

However, I have no idea where to go from here. A correlated subquery seems like it might be useful, but I'm not having much luck formulating one without errors. I'm not even sure if that's the correct approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your desired output should look like?

Comment: your query only considers bars that start and end between a foo's period. can't they overlap partially?

Comment: Arun The output I'm looking for is simply the foo ID and matching bar ID(s); Ollie Jones' answer nailed it. @1010 No, I specifically want to exclude all cases of overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your JOIN query is correct.  It picks up the (start--end) intervals that are entirely contained within your (arrive--depart) intervals. JOIN is the right choice for this.

Adding the invervals to the result set makes this easier to figure out:

```
SELECT foo.id AS fooid, arrive, depart,
       bar.id AS barid, start, end
  FROM foo 
  LEFT JOIN bar  
              ON bar.start >= foo.arrive 
             AND bar.end <= foo.depart
```

Here's a SQL fiddle showing that.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b7dc/3/0

Then, what you do is count the number of distinct "foo" items you have, and count the number of distinct combinations.  Then you join them together and you get the result you want. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed5ac/5/0

```
SELECT a.fooid, b.barid
  FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
             id AS fooid
        FROM foo
       GROUP BY id
        ) AS a
   JOIN (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
              foo.id AS fooid,
              bar.id AS barid
         FROM foo 
         LEFT JOIN bar  
                    ON bar.start >= foo.arrive 
                   AND bar.end <= foo.depart
        GROUP BY foo.id, bar.id
         ) AS b ON a.count=b.count AND a.fooid = b.fooid
```

I think this does what you want. But without a more thorough explanation, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I agree. I'd swap the join and left join to include foos without bars.